# Rails automatically pull out resource from nested resources in routes helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have nested resources like so

```
resources :users do
  resources :widgets
end
```

When I have `@widget`, to get a proper routing from my helpers i need to use `user_widget_path(@widget.user, @widget)` is there any way to tell rails to automatically pull out the user from `@widget` object? So i could just use `user_widget_path(@widget)`

Comment: based on feedback, sounds like there is not built in rails way to do this. Though based on the up votes sounds like it would be decent addition to the default routing helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@apneadiving is totally right. But you can improve a little your approach:

```
 link_to "user", user_widget_path(@widget.user, @widget)
```

can be presented shorter:

```
 link_to "user", [@widget.user, @widget]
```

**UPD**

Also you can rewrite `user_widget_path` as you want:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :user_widget_path
  private
  def user_widget_path(widget)
    super(widget.user, widget)
  end
end
```

You should also rewrite `edit_user_widget_path`, `new_user_widget_path`. And better to wrap it as an external Module.

Comment: That's exactly the helper I was writing! +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic method to do this. But you could create your own application helper, it's pretty straight.